# DRF post to model with a many-to-many field

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Tag(TimeStampModel):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

class Deal(VoteModel, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='deals',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=1024, unique=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    poster = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tag, blank=True)
```

And the following serializers:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'slug', 'featured', 'created_at']


class DealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    tags_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, write_only=True, queryset=Tag.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Deal
        fields = '__all__'
```

`Views`

```
class DealList(viewsets.ModelViewSet, VoteMixin):
    serializer_class = DealSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrAdminOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Deal.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

I am able to get the data and also post it, but because of the many-to-many field (`tags`), I seem to have some issues as a `Deal` may have `tags` that only exist (created beforehand, and cannot be created through a post request to the Deal).
I send data as the following:

```
{
    title: 'some title',
    all_other_fields: 'some data',
    tags_ids: [2, 4]
}
```

The tags are sent as an array of tag ids, but I get an error as the following:

`"Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."`

I only added the `tags_ids` so I could perform write operations on it as I couldn't figure out a way to use the field `tags` as both a read and write field that would return an object on read, and accept an id on write.

I have read through many posts here on Stackoverflow, but nothing that would work for me yet. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: just to make sure I understand what you are saying correctly, part of your requirements is that tags will be created before and can't be created with the deal, right ? so you are sure that the tags ids you get are valid ids

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your serializer like this

```py
class DealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Tag.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Deal
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way.

```
class DealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    tags = TagSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Deal
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'slug', 'description', 'poster', 'tags')
```